# Is it a right way to response when query database?

Tags: node.js, express, node-orm2

I use express and MySql with node-orm2.

There is a GET request to get some data from database.

```
var loginFormChecker = function (phone, pwd, cb) {
    var ret = {};

    userBaseModel.exists({
        phone: phone,
        password: pwd
    }, function (err, exists) {
        if (err) {
            // database error
            ret = new returnData({
                error: error.database,
                type: 0
            });
        } else {
            ret = new returnData({
                data: exists,
                type: 1
            });
        }

        cb(ret);
    });
};

router.route('/login')
.get(function (req, res) {
    var query = req.query;

    var output = function (ret) {
        if (ret) {
            res.send(ret);
        } else {
            res.status(500).send('something broken!');
        }
    };

    userService.loginFormChecker(query.p, query.k, output);
});
```

I pass the output function to loginFormChecker, and call it in the callback of querying data.

I do not know whether it is a right way to do it. Is there a better way to do, maybe promise or something?

Thanks.

Comment: In case `pwd` is plain stored in your db, that would be the first thing to check and solve.

Comment: @moonwave99, this is an example code. I will revise it later. Thanks

Comment: `if (ret) {
            res.send(ret);
        } else {
            res.status(500).send('something broken!');
        }` will always run the first clause `res.send(ret);`